# dropdown menu doesn't close when I click it again at menu mobile responsive user

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a website navigation bar that includes a dropdown menu in responsive. However, I'm facing an issue where the dropdown menu doesn't close when I click outside of it. I've tried adding the data-bs-auto-close="outside" attribute to the dropdown toggle element, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

````
  <!-- Navbar code omitted for brevity -->

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
    <div class="container-fluid gx-0">
      <div class="row gx-0 px-lg-2 py-lg-1">
        <div class="col-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center order-lg-1 order-2">
          <!-- Social media icons omitted for brevity -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11 order-lg-2 order-1 px-2 float-right mb-md-0 mb-1">
          <div class="navbar-nav gap-0 navlinks mt-lg-0 mt-4 nav justify-content-end">
            <!-- Other navigation links omitted for brevity -->
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdownMenu" id="dropdownMenu" data-bs-auto-close="outside" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <!-- Dropdown menu content omitted for brevity -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>```

<script src="<?=base_url()?>/<?=$publicimagepath?>frontdesign/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

dropdown menu doesn't close when I click it again at menu mobile user

I'm working on a website navigation bar that includes a dropdown menu in responsive. However, I'm facing an issue where the dropdown menu doesn't close when I click outside of it. I've tried adding the data-bs-auto-close="outside" attribute to the dropdown toggle element, but it doesn't seem to be working.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just need to add some JavaScript Code to solve this problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Navigation Bar</title>

  <!-- CSS dependencies -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .mega-menu {
      /* Add your styles for the dropdown menu  */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
      <div class="container-fluid gx-0">
        <div class="row gx-0 px-lg-2 py-lg-1">
          <div class="col-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center order-lg-1 order-2">
            <!-- Social media icons omitted for brevity -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-11 order-lg-2 order-1 px-2 float-right mb-md-0 mb-1">
            <div class="navbar-nav gap-0 navlinks mt-lg-0 mt-4 nav justify-content-end">
              <!-- Other navigation links omitted for brevity -->
              <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdownMenu" id="dropdownMenu" data-bs-auto-close="outside" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu mega-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
<a>test</t>
                <!-- Dropdown menu content omitted for brevity -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- JavaScript dependencies -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript  code for drobDown menu -->
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var dropdownElement = document.getElementById('dropdownMenu');
      var dropdown = new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownElement, {
        autoClose: 'outside'
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `  .navbar-nav div:hover>.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    background: #291515 !important;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}`
main the is issue code make .navbar-nav div display: block just i move this css @medai query min-width 992 and add your code thanks